# Check if document exists, if not create and add data Firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

As above I need create a function that returns "true" if a document exists, otherwise "false".
If the document doesn't exists then It need to be created before the function ends.

When I run it I have this exception :

```
Unhandled Exception: 'package:cloud_firestore/src/firestore.dart': Failed assertion: line 129 pos 12: 
'isValidDocumentPath(documentPath)': a document path must point to a valid document.
```

Is pretty easy to understand that I'm not checking if the path exists before getting the collection but I don't know how to handle it.

This is the code:

```
Future<bool> checkMissingId(String id) async {
  String str = id.toLowerCase();
  String letter = str[0];

    final snapShot =
        await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(letter).doc(str).get();

    if (snapShot == null || !snapShot.exists) {
      //if not exists then create it
      final _service = FirestoreService.instance;
      _service.setData(
        path: letter + str,
        data: {'id': id},
      );
      return true;
    } else // it already exists, return false
      return false;
}
```

EDIT : new code but still doesn't work :

```
Future<bool> checkMissingId(String id) async {
  String str = id.toLowerCase();
  String letter = str[0];
  String path = letter + "/" + str;
  print(path);

  try {
    final snapShot =
        await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(path).doc(str).get();

    if (snapShot == null || !snapShot.exists) {
      return true;
    } else
      return false;
  } catch (e) {
    print(e);
    return false;
  }
}

Future<bool> setId(String id) async {
  String str = id.toLowerCase();
  String letter = str[0];
  String path = letter + "/" + str;
  final _service = FirestoreService.instance;

  try {
    final snapShot =
        await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(path).doc(str).get();

    if (snapShot == null || !snapShot.exists) {
      _service.setData(
        path: path,
        data: {'id': id},
      );
      return true;
    } else
      return false;
  } catch (e) {
    //print(e);
    _service.setData(
      path: path,
      data: {'id': id},
    );
    return true;
  }
}
```

Assuming `id = "PaninoAvvelenato"` :
I want to check if exists the document on path "p/paninoavvelenato", if not I need to create it.

Comment: what are you passing in as str ?

Comment: Str is a name that must be lower case.
The idea is that "Str" will be the document inside the collection "letter" and "id" will be the data inside it using "data: {'id': id}"

Comment: In case you don't know, you don't have to check if a document exists. If it does not exist FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Test').doc(str).set({'Example': example,}) will create one. In case it does, it will update the data in the document.

Comment: @Florian I know how "set" works, my need is : if the document already exists then I don't need to do anything, just return true, but if it exists I need to create it and return false.

Comment: I'm curious about what you are passing in as str. The reason behind the question is if you are passing in some invalid characters, or an invalid document path. You mention that str is a name. I hope without white spaces...? And if you specify the path, make sure that collections are ending with a forward slash.

Comment: @RobertSandberg User chooses a name like "Potato". This name will be transformed with .toLowerCase() method and a document will be created inside the path "firstLetterOfTheUserId/userId" (p/potato).
With data : id no lowercase. Now I used as test the string "PaninoAvvelenato" and it doesn't work because the path, obviously, didn't exist. I don't want to set anything, just check because if this userId is already used by someone then I need to notify this and ask for a new ID, that's it.

Comment: Yes, I understand the lowerCase and so forth. I was checking what you are passing in as str. I don't follow you on what "doesn't work because the path obviously didn't exist". Are you checking somewhere else if the document exists or not? What I think your code seems to do is: check if p/paninoavvelenato doesn't exist. If that is true, meaning it doesn't exist, you try to create a path as letter + str. That is ppaninoavvelenato. Then you are missing a forward slash between letter and str, when your code is trying to create that path. How you use .get() and snapShot.exists is correct.

Comment: @RobertSandberg I modified the code thank you, what you said is correct but it sill doesn't work, I will edit the original post but I think I'm close to the solution. 
By the way your thought is right, I want to create a path (if it doesn't exist) p/paninoavvelenato, correct with data "id".

Comment: What still doesn't work? Where do you use checkMissingId() ? What is FirestoreService? Why are you not using FirebaseFirestore.instance ?

Comment: Now you've added path to as part of your collection. That's not correct. I'll write an answer. Hopefully that will work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using FirestoreService.

```
Future<bool> setId(String id) async {
  String str = id.toLowerCase();
  String letter = str[0];

  try {
    final snapShot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(letter).doc(str).get();

    if (snapShot.exists) {
      return false;
    } else {
      await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(letter).doc(str).set({'id': id});
      return true;
    }
  } catch (e) {
    // TODO: Do something clever.
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: Mh I didn't get you, this works ok but I always used FirestoreService and it worked, why now it doesn't work and I need to do it with FirebaseFirestore...Which is the difference?

Comment: I don't know what FirestoreService is.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, FirestoreService is a custom class created by me where I call FirebaseFirestore services, set, get...So it's a custom way to use FirebaseFirestore nothing more

Answer (score 0):

It looks like document for path str is not exist and FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(letter).doc(str).get(); throw exception

so better to place this code inside :

```
try { 
   // code that might throw an exception 
   FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(letter).doc(str).get();
}  
on Exception1 { 
   // code for handling exception 
}  
catch Exception2 { 
   // code for handling exception 
}
```

Comment: I already tried using "try" and "catch" but it doesn't work...My app doesn't stop running just doesn't write data on the DB